# How to add more space between Y-axis and bar chart in Altair visual

Tags: python, altair

This is the chart I have now:

[image: 1]

I'd like to make more space between the percent label and the start of the bar chart, similar to this chart:

[image: 2]

This is the code I'm working on:

```
chart = alt.Chart(percentages_df).mark_bar(size=17, color= '#DAC352', dx=100).encode(
    x=alt.X(
        'PERCENT',axis=None),
    y=alt.Y(
        'PERCENT_TEXT',
         axis=alt.Axis(domain=False, tickSize=0,title='') ,sort='-y'))

text = alt.Chart(percentages_df).mark_text().encode(
    y=alt.Y('PERCENT_TEXT',axis=None, sort='-y'),
    text='EMOJI'
)
new_chart = alt.hconcat(text, chart).configure_view(strokeWidth=0).configure_axis(grid=False)
new_chart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `labelPadding` axis property, which specifies the space between the labels and ticks in pixels. For example:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x = 'b',
    y=alt.Y('a', axis=alt.Axis(domain=False, tickSize=0, labelPadding=10))
)
```

[image]